# SQL Server Query - Split a string into 3 parts based on 2 different common delimiters

Tags: sql-server, string, substring, charindex

I'm trying to build a query that can split combined product descriptions, colors, and sizes into their individual values.  I have a table full of product descriptions, colors, and sizes.  Some of the product descriptions contain the color and the size each delimited with a specific string.  Some of the colors and sizes are contained in their own columns.  Many times, both the description and the color/size columns contain both color/size values.  A common product description combined with color and size would look like this:
ProductDescription..-..Color--.--Size where Color is delimited by "..-.." and Size is delimited by "--.--".  Sometimes color and/or size do not exist and there is no delimiter for the query to refer to, but I still want it to split the description/color or description/size, or just return the description and blank values for color/size when neither exists...

Description and Size split up just fine, but I'm having trouble with color. I get the following error:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's what I have so far that isn't working:

```
Select
    Ps.ID
    ,Case
        When Ps.ColorStart <= 5 And Ps.SizeStart <= 5 Then Ps.Description
        When Ps.ColorStart <= 5 And Ps.SizeStart > 5 Then Left(Ps.Description, Ps.SizeStart - 6)
        When Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then Left(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart - 6)
        Else Ps.Description
    End As DescriptionWithoutColorAndSize

    ,Case
        When Ps.PColor Is Not Null And Ps.PColor <> '' Then Ps.PColor
        When Ps.ColorStart <= 5 Or Ps.Description Is Null Or Ps.Description = '' Then ''
        When Ps.SizeStart <= 5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299)
        When Ps.SizeStart > 5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1)
            --The prior line is what fails
        Else ''
    End As Color


    ,Case
        When Ps.PSize Is Not Null And Ps.PSize <> '' Then Ps.PSize
        When Ps.SizeStart <= 5 Then ''
        Else SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.SizeStart, 299)
    End As Size

From
    (
    Select
        P.ID
        ,P.Description
        ,P.Color As PColor
        ,P.Size As PSize
        ,CHARINDEX('..-..',P.Description,0) + 5 As ColorStart
        ,CHARINDEX('--.--',P.Description,0) -1 As ColorEndIfSizeExists
        ,Len(P.Description) As ColorEndIfSizeDoesNotExist
        ,CHARINDEX('--.--',P.Description,0) + 5 As SizeStart

    From
        MYProductsTable P
    ) Ps
```

Comment: what does your query return when you just have SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1) in the select statement?

Comment: Was wondering about that to, as you're not checking the length of ColorEndIfSizeExists before running the calc.

Comment: I get the same error.  It is possible for the description to be null or blank as well, and I've tried to account for that in the 2nd line of that case statement, but this might be causing the error anyway...  I just can't tell because it errors out.

Comment: try writing the columns involved in this particular substring in a select statement and see if either one is null, if yes then just use ISNULL and default it to 0

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with my Case statement setup...  For some reason the 3rd line in that Color case statement is not being triggered even when as far as I can tell it is true...  When Ps.SizeStart <= 5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299).  How is that possible?

Comment: does Ps.ColorStart have any nulls in it or some string in it?

Comment: It isn't possible @Sushil because some of the values involved are definitely incorrect in some scenarios.  That's why I have the case statement set up to try to account for all of the potential scenarios that exist.  But that doesn't actually appear to be working...

Comment: Ps.ColorStart doesn't have any nulls; none of the calculated values from the subquery do.

Comment: without the data, I can only guess.. can you create an sqlfiddle if possible?

Comment: I had never heard of sqlfiddle before.  Unfortunately the data produced by the subquery is over 248,000 unique rows and sqlfiddle seems to be struggling with that.

Comment: This time I really did figure it out.  Had to add a new When to the Color case statement:  When Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1 < 0 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the problems were related to the following case statement:

```
,Case
    When Ps.PColor Is Not Null And Ps.PColor <> '' Or Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1 < 0 Then Ps.PColor
    When Ps.ColorStart <=5 Or Ps.Description Is Null Or Ps.Description = '' Then ''
    When Ps.SizeStart <=5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299)
    When Ps.SizeStart > 5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1)

    Else ''
End As Color
```

I changed all instances of "<=5" to "<6", and added a new When to the statment as follows:

```
    ,Case
        When Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1 < 0 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299)
        When Ps.PColor Is Not Null And Ps.PColor <> '' Then Ps.PColor
        When Ps.ColorStart <6 Or Ps.Description Is Null Or Ps.Description = '' Then ''
        When Ps.SizeStart <6 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, 299)
        When Ps.SizeStart > 5 And Ps.ColorStart > 5 Then SUBSTRING(Ps.Description, Ps.ColorStart, Ps.ColorEndIfSizeExists - Ps.ColorStart + 1)
        Else ''
    End As Color
```

And that fixed the problem.  I don't know why...  If anyone does, please feel free to explain!
Thanks for all the input.